# Cookie for wkhtmltppdf using IIS7

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf creating PDF from my html site. This works fine in development but when I upload it to the webserver with IIS7 I have the problem with the user.

In the site I use the windows authentification to log on the current user and also display the username on the site.

But the problem is that wenn the pdf is generating the current user isn't used so that I get an error. I don't want to use a temp-user for login (wkhtmltopdf.exe --username...) because this would be displayed on the website and also on the pdf.

Already tried the impersonate

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
</system.web>
```

but then I get

```
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers
```

I looked around and tried for a while but get no working solution for me to create a cookie or something like that and give it to wkhtmltopdf to create the pdf with the current user logged on.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Forms Authentication, you can use the `--cookie` option to pass the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie to wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Can you please give me a little example? I normally use Windows Authentification for the whole website